# Could someone please identify this plant?

Tags: identification

[image]
I need help identifying this plant, it may have made my dog sick.

Comment: Where does this plant grow? And the holes / tears are bite marks, I presume?

Comment: Yes, the holes and tears are most likely from the puppies. We are located in Southeast Michigan.

Comment: What symptoms are the puppy or puppies displaying.. I sure hope you've taken them to the vet!!  Do you see any other plants like this in your yard, neighbor's yard?  Have you shown this to your neighbors?

Answer (score 3):

After some super input from 'someone else', we should consider Arctium lappa or Common Burdock.  These leaves in the picture are of a plant without fertilizer and only periodic watering.  Burdock leaves can get huge with lots of water and a bit of fertilizer!  Look at the margins, overall shape, color and if we were to pull that plant out of there we could see that root.

If this answer is correct, then I doubt this caused the puppies any sickness. I'd like to hear what the symptoms of those puppies were?  What the veterinarians have found.  Please say they are fine now, those puppies or puppy is still fine?!

Answer (score 2):

This plant is definitely burdock.  Its leaves can become massive and in its second year it will send up a large flower stalk with seeds that mature as spiny burs like velcro that will stick to your clothes.  Cool plant - has medicinal qualities.  Leaves are extremely bitter so I doubt your pet would want to eat it!  If you want to remove it, dig out as much of the taproot which can get very deep as you can.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research this looks like Digitalis or Foxglove.[digitalis picture of leaves](http://garden.org/plants/photo/306394/http://)

How are your puppies/puppy/dog?  What were the symptoms?  After looking at the pictures I sent you, does this plant look familiar?

Foxglove is very poisonous.  Let your veterinarian see these pictures, they SHOULD be well versed with poisonous plants for dogs and cats!  So MANY are in our yards!!  When your pets are outside they should be supervised and taught to not eat any plant material.  Cats are far more vulnerable as people allow them to become the 'neighborhood' cat (grrrrrr) and ALL lilies of all kinds are very poisonous to cats in particular but dogs as well.

What other plants are in your yard?

Comment: I don't think this is a foxglove - not sure what it is though, maybe one of the Verbascums

Comment: This ain't easy as this plant is not true to form.  I used to have a nice little library where I could figure out these botanical mysteries.  There is so much on the internet and have not been happy with any of the keys.  What do you recommend? I'll go back and cogitate a bit more...

Comment: I've been scouring the internet myself, drawn a blank - the closest is mullein or verbascum rather than foxglove, but I'm not convinced its that either - this one looks very floppy and its in poor condition, whatever it is. If its mullein, its unlikely to have caused sickness, but then puppies eat practically anything, so it may not be this that caused the trouble anyway

Comment: The venation is Digitalis, the edges the rounded serration, the color of dusty bluish weeds by a driveway? Basal growth...I'll hold onto Digitalis for my bet until we get more information, grins!!

Comment: Digitalis would certainly cause vomiting...

Comment: To imagine this particular plant is the cause would be pretty amazing that this guy was so vigilant.  Very possible that this is Digitalis.  Has he/she reported the symptoms yet?  Looked up Verbascum and way too tomentose for the OP's plant...I think anyway, grins.

Comment: What about Arctium lappa?

Comment: Whoa Brenn!  Sure looks like it.  If we could just get a burr or dig his plant up to see the roots...good job!  You should make an answer!  I had no idea that burdock leaves got so huge.  Tough to make out the margins because the scale is so big.  If this was eaten by a puppy, this wouldn't make him sick would it.  So he'd have to look elsewhere.

Comment: Take it @stormy. I'm pretty sure it's common burdock.

Comment: Brenn!  This is YOUR answer!!  Put your neck out there and do an answer.  I think you are right, as right as I'd need to be to make an answer!  When others give a bid for an ID it helps everyone and makes the final answer more credible!  This is YOUR ANSWER...!!!!  Grins...good job.  It still might be wrong but my goodness it is better than my guess!!  Brenn, I am very curious...who are you?

Comment: Just took a peek...handsome young man doing very well with the language of gardening!  New people especially those that have learned this language all by themselves through experience have valuable new insights.  Anyone who is young that understands this 'language' will have very interesting and valuable insight.  Us oldies worry about being too stuck in a rut...we need you.  You have an awful lot to offer and I will be watching for your answers...

Comment: @Stormy, I love your posts! You put more love and passion into them than anyone else here.  By far!  Alas, I'm tired of competing for silly points on this site. All I want to do here is to provide accurate IDs and info for those that can benefit from it. Please and always, feel free to take my IDs and post them as answers.  As long as you believe them to be accurate, of course.

Comment: Well Brenn, I really am enjoying your wonderful words. I'm doing an 'aw shucks' head down, little grin thingy.  But you aren't getting out of this that easily.  Your rationalization is very rationale but I know better.  When you put your neck out there for others to chop off, there is also the chance that you will get wild applause! No school in the world can replace taking risks by putting your opinions out there to be scrutinized, dissected, questioned then learning whether your opinion is right, somewhat right or gotta go back to the drawing board.

Comment: Thanks @stormy. Perhaps this should be moved to the meta or chat site. I fear we're hijacking this post. That said. Keep up your awesome and insightful posts. I'm going to be more of a lurker from herein.  Too much politics. Sigh.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I know.  And now I understand a bit more!!  Huggs!  Interesting...